# what options to convert this to a string?

Tags: python, string

I need following desired output so that I can copy and paste into another program. Not sure how to use the correct string syntax.

```
A = 10 
B = 20
u = np.linspace(0, 2* np.pi*57.3, 1000)
print((A+B)*cos(u))
```

Output:

```
30
```

Desired Output

```
(10+20)*cos(u)
```

Comment: How about f-string : `print(f'({A}+{B})*cos(u)')`?

Answer (score 3):

Easier way for `.format()`:

```
import numpy as np

A = 10 
B = 20
u = np.linspace(0, 2* np.pi*57.3, 1000)

print(f'({A}+{B})*cos({u})')
```

**OUTPUT**:
`(10+20)*cos("value of u")`

Comment: So you just copied from the comments??

Comment: I did not read the comments im new to stackoverflow thank you for your comment i will read the comments first @JeruLuke

Comment: I presumed you did so. Welcome to SO!!

Comment: sometimes, "stealing" from the comments is explicitly okay, other times it's frowned upon. it always changes. for such trivial questions, it can't possibly matter because string formatting is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
print('(%.d + %.d)*cos(u)' %(A, B))
```

Comment: that `%` is old and deprecated syntax. these days, f-strings (`f"..."`) or `"...".format()` is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.format()` function to insert certain variable values into a string by writing `{}` in it whenever you need to add those values:

```
import numpy as np

A = 10 
B = 20
u = np.linspace(0, 2* np.pi*57.3, 1000)
print((A+B)*np.cos(u))

print('({}+{})*cos(u)'.format(A, B))
```

**Output:**

```
(10+20)*cos(u)
```